# MySQL Error: Unknown column in 'field list' PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Hey guys I have a problem with MySQL, i'm trying to insert data in a table but it's returning this error message

> Fatal error: SQL: SELECT e.idtarea AS 'idTarea', e.detalle AS 'detalle', e.precio AS 'precio', e.idor AS 'idOrdenReparacion', e.fecha AS 'fecha', concat( 'Editar ', 'Eliminar' ) AS Opciones FROM Tarea e WHERE e.idtarea like '%%' ORDER BY e.idtarea;, Error: Unknown column 'e.idor' in 'field list' in /opt/lampp/htdocs/scep/tareas.php on line 76

**Here is my code:**

```
$SQL="

  SELECT 
    e.idtarea AS 'idTarea', 
    e.detalle AS 'detalle', 
    e.precio AS 'precio', 
    e.idor AS 'idOrdenReparacion', 
    e.fecha AS 'fecha', 
    concat('<a href=\'editarTarea.php?id=',e.idtarea,'\'>Editar</a>&nbsp;','<a href=\'eliminarTarea.php?id=',e.idtarea,'\' onclick=javascript:confirm(\'Eliminar?>\')>Eliminar </a>') AS Opciones 
  FROM Tarea e ".$FILTRAR_POR." 
  ORDER BY e.idtarea;";

  $RESULT = mysql_query($SQL) or trigger_error("SQL: $SQL, Error: " . mysql_error(), E_USER_ERROR);
```

**Table Tarea from database:**

```
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Tarea` (
   `idTarea` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `detalle` varchar(45) COLLATE latin1_danish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
   `precio` varchar(45) COLLATE latin1_danish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
   `idOrdenReparacion` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   `fecha` date DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`idTarea`,`idOrdenReparacion`),
   KEY `fk_Tarea_OrdenReparacion1_idx` (`idOrdenReparacion`)
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_danish_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;

.....

  ALTER TABLE `Tarea`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_Tarea_OrdenReparacion1` FOREIGN KEY (`idOrdenReparacion`) 
  REFERENCES `OrdenReparacion` (`idOrdenReparacion`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Well... guess what... there is no `idor` column in your table.

Comment: yes I just solved by writing e.idOrdenReparacion, but now i have the same error with e.fecha, but fecha does really exists

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have `idor` column in `Tarea` table, but you're trying to select it.

Comment: I just solved by writing e.idOrdenReparacion, but now i have the same error with e.fecha, but fecha does really exists